# Why would AWS Beanstalk CLI deploy not start the web app or cause a proxy server error on the second deployment but not the first?

Tags: go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I get an nginx 502 error when deploying my application to Beanstalk after the 1st successful deployment. The web application is written in Go. If no files are changed why would the second(and so on) deployments fail?

I can use the AWS CLI to create and deploy a BeanStalk Go application following this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_go.html

I have the following files:

Procfile:
`web: bin/application`
Buildfile::
`make: ./build.sh`
build.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
go build -o bin/application ./cmd/web/
```

I create/deploy the first time with: `eb create test-env --elb-type application` and everything works fine and I can access the web app.

But after the first time when I use `eb deploy` then the instance health degrades as I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

So it would appear that the web app isn't being started or the proxy server settings are changing but zero files have changed between deployments. What can I look for to help troubleshoot this file?

EDIT:
I did find that going to Actions and rebuilding the environment brings the app up working okay. It only breaks if I do eb deploy. And then I can rebuild the environment and it works again. So it seems like its not a path or configuration issue else it wouldn't work after rebuilding.

EDIT:
I am able to to eb deploy and the application works fine if I first build the application using : `GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -o bin/application ./cmd/web/` It appears for some reason my Buildfile isn't running after the first create. At least it is working now so hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Can you login to the EB instance and inspect from the inside, e.g. using `curl` if your app is working? Also have you chcecked any EB logs?

Comment: Yes, I logged in and was able to use curl to get a response successfully. The port is 5000 as expected. So it seems the web app is working and it must be a nginx config issue? As for logs, I am not sure what to look for eactly. The nginx error.log has ```[error] 4020#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.28.130, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.23.18"```

Comment: I don't understand this, but if I do ```eb deploy``` then it degrades and I get 502. But when I used SSH to connect it had to setup SSH and the eb ssh command auto restarted the server it started working. If I do 'eb deploy' again it goes down. Manually restarting the server does not bring it back up.

Comment: Have you done any modifications to your EB, e.g. using `.ebextentions`? Since you are using ALB, maybe health checks are incorrectly set?

Comment: I have not made any modifications to .ebextensions. I did another eb deploy and then ssh'd into the intance again and now the app is responding to request with 'Connection refused' so I am thinking the app is not running now.

Comment: Ok, looking in the log I see this: ```env: bin/application: No such file or directory``` which is where the app should be. My build.sh builds it so doesn't eb deploy run that which is in my Buildfile? It does it on eb create so I assumed it would do it on deploy.

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html) they write about about `bin/application`. Maybe you have to adjust something to build your app they way EB expects?

Comment: I am following the tutorial from the above link. It creates and deploys it the first time okay so I would think it should continue to work.